# "Undeclared identifier" when trying to define function template

Tags: c++, templates

I want to define a function that decides whether two arrays of doubles are (approximately) equal. Here's my code:

```
Comparisons.h :

#pragma once
#include <array>

const double EPSILON = 0.0001;

bool areFuzzyEqual(const double& d1, const double& d2);

template<int n>
bool fuzzyEquality((const std::array<double, n>)& a1, (const std::array<double, n>)& a2) {
    bool retVal = True;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        retVal &= areFuzzyEqual(a1[i], a2[i]);
    }
    return retVal;
};
```

When I try to compile this project I get errors like

Error   C2065   'a1': undeclared identifier

Error   C3861   'a1': identifier not found

I don't understand where this error comes from. They're parameters, why would I need to define them?

Comment: Also if anyone can give me a hint on how to do this same function but with streams I would really appreciate it (something like using std::accumulate but without having to make an auxiliary array a1 - a2)

Comment: I'm not in front of a compiler but my first guess would be the brackets round the arguments which are unnecessary. You should look at the full compiler output for more details rather than the error summary window

Comment: Why are you putting parenthesis around your types?

Comment: It was the parenthesis, yeah. I don't know why they're there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just rewrite this line

`bool fuzzyEquality((const std::array<double, n>)& a1, (const std::array<double, n>)&a2)`

as

`bool fuzzyEquality(const std::array<double, n>& a1, const std::array<double, n>& a2)`

and you should be good.